# Is passing the id or primary key in URLS safe for editing in symfony2 doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

My urls are like below for controllers like

`/user/profile/{id}/edit`

Now i don't find it verysafe , because if the previleged member enter any other numeric there , then data will be inserted in wrong user.

Basically i have the form on front page with select list of students , teacher then selects the student and then it goes further. Here i am submitting the form and setting the `userid` in session variable.

Few things pages work fine because i am not putting any variable in URL.

But i get stuck where i have the list of assignemnts added by user. As i am displaying in table format and every click goes to separate assigment . i have to put the `assignmentid` in the URL

Is there any way to tackle this so that i don't need to put anything in URL

Comment: I am not familiar with symfony and doctrine - do you have the ability to write your own queries and execute them to fetch results, or are they rather locked down deep within objects?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should assume every user input/action may be wrong or evil: so, implement verification under the Symfony2 firewall and isGranted function to check if an user has rights to edit an user.

Secondly, maybe you should give instead an id in the url an username or an user slug: it would be more difficult then to reach the edit pages by farming all the user ids of your base

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with passing the IDs through the URL. You *could* use `POST` or `SESSION` data to pass the IDs around, but it can be cumbersome and annoying for users because it can upset browser history navigation.

Instead, you should be doing privilege verification on every request if security is a concern. If the problem is an aesthetic one and not a security one, you could create a unique name for each assignment that you can pass in the URL instead.